# Is it possible to fragment your data into different Redis stores that you load into memory when needed?

Tags: ruby, database, nosql, redis

I've read up on the Virtual Memory feature of Redis, and it seems very interesting and useful.  But I was wondering if there was a way to do something different.  I'm going to have a situation where I have very discrete blocks of data per user, with up to 10s of millions of rows for power users (but often only a 100k rows for casual users).  It would be great if I could have a separate Redis store for each user, and load their data store from disk into memory when they come online, and then back to disk when they go offline.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long story short, **No**. Redis does not have a way to selectively load data in and out of RAM. Redis loads data based on its "popularity" and its frequency of access, and the amount of system RAM. The more RAM, the more Redis will try to store.

I would recommend you suggest this to the developers, as it would be very useful feature.

Comment: Thanks Colum, I did put it in as a feature request.  Do you know of any data store that could accomplish this?

Comment: Also, would it be possible or practical to build a system where you have a separate port per user and just fire up or close down ports depending on whether a user is online?

Comment: Yes it would be possible, but it would not practical. If you have 100 users coming on and offline, then that would become server intensive. You would be causing more load that saving (in my view)

Comment: @JeremySmith Do you have a link to the feature request, by any chance? It'd be nice to see if it was implements, or *why* it was denied if it was.